# Is there a command to kill all mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to kill all mobs other than `/kill @e`?  For some reason, it kills me too. Someone told me to do something like

```
 /kill @e{type=Zombie}
```

but every time I put it in, nothing happens.

Comment: **minecraftplzhelp** nice name lol

Comment: @e effects all entities, that includes players and yourself

Answer (score 4):

If it's vanilla version, you can use

> /kill @e[type=Zombie]

you were using `{}` instead of `[]`, that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
/kill @e[team=,type=!Player]
```

to kill all mobs, this saves items and other entities that aren't mobs.

Comment: Be aware this will also kill armor stands.

Answer (score 2):

Selector parameters must be encased in square brackets, not curly brackets:

```
/kill @e[type=Zombie]
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you wish to kill all entities (Including items, item frames, etc.) excluding the player, you could do:

`/kill @e[type=!Player]`